# Get variable out of array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I have a newbie question. I want to work with arrays, but I can't reach arrays within an array. Like this :

```
function myFunction() { 

    var id1 = 1
    var id2= "test"
    var X = [5]
    var id = [[id1, X], [id2]]

    Logger.log(id[0]);
    Logger.log(id[0,1]);
}
```

How do I only get the X here inside the array? I assumed the second logger would return the [5] - but no, it returns "test".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference variables with multiple indexes one after another, like so (using your Logger syntax):

```
Logger.log(id[0][1]);
```